# Get JavaScript intellisense with closures in VS 2019

Tags: javascript, closures, visual-studio-2019, intellisense, self-invoking-function

I organize my JavaScript code into "modules" to get namespace-like access such as `foo.bar()` and to hide internals from the global namespace.

```
var foo = foo || {};

// Intellisense would work for these declarations:
foo.bla = 0;
foo.blub = true;

// Self-invoking function for the module "foo".
(
    function () {

        // This closure represents the module "foo".
        
        // Intellisense is not working for any of these (from the outside):
        foo.bar = "bar";

        foo.baz = function () {
            const bazMessage = "baz";
            showMessage(bazMessage);
        };

        foo.bazz = function () {
            const bazzMessage = "bazz";
            showMessage(bazzMessage);
        };

        // This function is "private" and not seen globally.
        function showMessage(message) {
            alert(message);
        }
    }
);
```

My problem now is that Visual Studio does not provide intellisense for anything which is added to `foo` from within the module.

- Does anyone know a possibility to get intellisense working for the described scenario?
- Does anyone know an alternative way to accomplish namespace-like access and have intellisense?

Comment: Why not use ES6 modules? That should provide correct intellisense. The problem with the current code is that it's hard to analyse. You can probably annotate it with JSDoc to aid the intellisense but it's more work for you.

Comment: @VLAZ I will take ES6 into consideration for my future development work but I have a code base where this is no option at the moment, but thank you anyway for your suggestion.